# Should residuals of a VAR model be autocorrelated?

Tags: autocorrelation, residuals, vector-autoregression

In VAR models, when we check for autocorrelation on the residuals, what is the desired result? Should residuals be autocorrelated, because it is time-series, or autocorrelation is not good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The residuals should be uncorrelated, just as in a basic linear model.

Uncorrelated residuals are needed for OLS and/or maximum likelihood estimators to have the standard asymptotic distributions. Presence of autocorrelation may cause the estimated standard errors to be too small and thus the coefficients to appear more precisely estimated (and more statistically significant) than they actually are.

Also, if the residuals are autocorrelated, there remains predictability in them. When such a VAR model is used for forecasting, it is fails to account for the autocorrelation, which yields suboptimal forecasts.

> Should residuals be autocorrelated, because it is time-series <...> ?

The original time series often tend to be autocorrelated, but the purpose of modelling is, among other, to account precisely for that and to yield a model where residuals are not autocorrelated.